# How to fix postinstall on a dependency with yarn?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a node dependency that has a simple postinstall step which includes a call to `mkdirp`.

with npm install - this was the structure

```
 +- project 
    +- node_modules
       +- dep1
          +- node_modules
             +- mkdirp
```

so when dep1 postinstall used mkdirp it would find it in the path

now it fails because with yarn mkdirp is not longer in the path.

how can I resolve this?

I tried running `npm install` on the specific dependency that is breaking, and only then run `yarn install` - but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/853), Yarn doesn't (yet) run `preinstall` or `postinstall` scripts. If you are using a package that relies on those hooks, it will fail.

With the release of NPM v5 and the supposed [5x speed-up](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161276872334/npm5-is-now-npmlatest), you might just want to stick with `npm`.

Comment: did exactly that! couple of weeks after posting the question they released 5, and I smiled for that same reason.

Comment: Looks like this has since been fixed: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/800